# How do I make a link with img into a text input/submit box that then passes whatever was entered to another page?

Tags: php, javascript, onclick

I am using the below code which points to the search page of my site.  However, I'd like to make it so when clicked, it opens a hidden drop down input box with a "Search" button.  Then when someone types a search query and clicks the button, it forwards this to the search page of my site and does the search.  I have no idea how to implement this as I'm a Javascript/PHP noob, but it seems like a cool mod for my site.  If anyone needs more code snippets, please let me know.  Thanks!

```
<a class="button_link_main" href="./search.php"><img src="/images/search.png" onmouseover="this.src='/images/searchsite_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='/images/search.png'" /></a>
```

Comment: if its hidden, how can it be typed in?

Comment: When clicked, the "hidden" box drops down with the input area. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a form with an input field and submit buttons in front of the link and give the <form> and <a> elements ids (here: searchForm and searchLink):

```
<form id="searchForm" action="./search.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
    <input type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="showSearchLink();return false;">
</form>
<a id="searchLink" class="button_link_main" href="./search.php" onclick="showSearchForm();return false;">Link</a>
```

Add this CSS code. It hides the complete <form> element on default:

```
#searchForm {
    display:none;
}
```

Lastly, add the following JavaScript functions in your <head>. (You could use an external file for example.)

```
function showSearchForm() {
    // show the form by setting style="display:inline"
    document.getElementById('searchForm').style.display = 'inline';
    // hide the link by setting style="display:none"
    document.getElementById('searchLink').style.display = 'none';
}

function showSearchLink() {
    // hide the form
    document.getElementById('searchForm').style.display = 'none';
    // show the link
    document.getElementById('searchLink').style.display = 'inline';
}
```

If a user clicks the Link, the onclick event calls the showSearchForm() function. The second command "return false;" prevents the browser from loading the ./search.php site directly. (This is useful if someone has JavaScript disabeld: he will be redirected directly to the ./search.php site.)

The onclick event of the cancel button does exactly the same. It calls the showSearchLink() function and then prevents the form from being submit.

You can test all the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/tKMt4/

If someone submits the form by clicking the search button, he will be redirected to ./search.php. You can receive and echo the input data in your PHP-Code with:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['q'];
?>
```

For tips on how to implement the search functionality itself, you should search for a good tutorial. The best thing would probably be to store your websites text content in a MySQL database.

Comment: thanks for the reply!  I'm not sure how to implement this on the actual search page, i.e. I don't know how to pass the variable and produce the search results. I tried to paste a snippet from my search page source code, but it was too long...

Comment: Would also like to be able to "cancel" the input box, and return to the Link.

Comment: I've updated the above answer. You are now able to hide the form and show the link again. For tips on how to implement the search itself, you should search for a good tutorial. If you have questions on how to implement the search, you should probably create a new question.

Comment: I am glad I could help you. You can mark the answer as correct so others can see that the question has been answered and they will find a solution here. Yes ... and of course I get a few points ;)

Comment: Cool, I will do that.  I also posted a new question with many more details about my search page.  Oh, one more thing with the above code, how do I get the cursor to focus on the input box when someone clicks the link?

Comment: Thanks. Here is an example for adding focus to the element:
http://jsfiddle.net/xZM9t/
I have added an id to the text input element and a single line in the JavaScript code that calls the "focus()" method.